# Deleting dynamic object

Tags: c++, dynamic

I have kind of a homework, and I'm stuck... The code looks like this:

```
class X {  
...  
};  

class Y {  
public:   
Y(X*);  
...  
};

int main () {  
X* px = new X;  
new Y(px);  
!@##   
}
```

The task:

The dynamic object of class Y, created with new Y(px), isn't lost at the place marked with !@## and can be deleted. How is it possible? Write additional code for classes X and Y, that deletes the object.

Comment: @DeadMG It was a citation from a task, probably :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution, that comes to my mind is:

- add one pointer to `Y` in `class X`
- in the constructor of `Y`, change the object, pointed by `X*` to have a pointer to the newly created `Y` object
- in the destructor of `X` free the memory, pointed by the pointer, which stores the address of the created `Y` object

---

I'll edit, because of a comment of @EdHeal: there's a potential problem, yes. Using this "method", you may try to delete more than once the same `Y` object (if it's passed to several `X` objects).

This is true, but it's a rare case.
If the pointer `X::Y*` is private and there's **no** getter for it (in other words, `X` is the one and only owner of this object `Y`), there's no such possibility.

To double+ delete the new `Y`, you **need** to pass some `X` object's pointer to `Y`, to another `X` object. In other words, something like:

```
X* px = new X;  
new Y(px); 
X* another_px = new X;
another_px->Y_pointer = px->Y_pointer; // or using some accessors
```

Comment: This can have the potential problem if creating multiple Xes using the same Ys - segmentation faults etc.

Comment: I down voted because to the potential problem that can be very difficult to track down. I have had experience of this.

Comment: @EdHeal - if it's designed carefully (and you make sure, what I say in my answer), there will be no any problems. You're right about the **potential** problem, but it can easily be avoided.

Comment: One problem is that quite a few software projects grow organically and therefore people are not aware of the potential pitfall. I just think that the best policy is for the "person" (i.e. scope, object, function etc) that uses `new` should also tidy up after itself. In that way this potential problem is avoided.

Comment: Still, this does not answer the question at all.

Answer (score 1):

Think about what's going on when the `Y(px)` gets executed. What's being called? How can you use it?

Comment: +1 for reading the question and not giving the answer away.

Answer (score 0):

It *is* lost, since you don't save the return value of `new Y` into an appropriate pointer variable.

If you don't want to lose it rewrite it this way:

```
Y* py = new Y(px);

// ...

delete py;
```

Comment: It *isn't* lost, that is stated in the question. One has to provide the mystery code such that is doesn't get lost.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I see, didn't understand this from question formulation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to hang on to the pointer from the new operator (`new Y(px);`).

i.e.

```
py = new Y(px);
```

Then just use delete on `px` and `py`

It is usually good policy for the thing that creates it should delete it.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all. And it's the same as @valdo's